# Selenium: Is there a way to change the hosts file on the machine the server is running on

Tags: selenium, hosts-file

I want to make the browser open a local url with a name of the live url. Meaning that when I do:

`sel.open('http://live-url/)`

selenium will actually open the local url.

One would test this by changing it's hosts file but this is impossible when running on many machines.

ideas?

Comment: Why do you want to do it this way?

Comment: It's the first thing I thought about. But anything that works is fine by me.

Comment: Same question as @AutomatedTester really... What are you achieving by masquerading as the live site? Perhaps there's a better way to do this? Also, why is changing the hosts file 'impossible when running on many machines'? I agree it's not ideal and could be a maintenance nightmare, but it shouldn't be *impossible*.

Comment: We redirect our `http://www.live-url` to `http://live-url` and we've had a bug that this redirect causes unexpected behavior. The inner and live site are filled with hacks that make this behavior unseen in the inner servers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No

Selenium cannot change the hosts file as it can only interact with pages rendered inside a broswer.

You could probably set your CI server up to do something like this, but again I have to ask why.  Hacking around with a site and then testing it will surely invalidate your tests?